# How can I compute obb and sphere collision in directx9?

Tags: collision, directx-9

How can I compute oriented bounding box and sphere collision? 
I need to find out the intersect point? But I do not know how, Please help me!

Comment: [DirectXMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/27/introducing-directxmath.aspx) includes the ability to detect intersections & containment using ``BoundingSphere`` and ``BoundingOrientedBox``, but does not provide the intersect point.

Comment: Thank you! It work! But how can I know the box orient when I rotate it?

Comment: And how should I set 'w' axis?

Comment: DirectXMath's bounding box uses a quaternion to represent the rotation. You can use functions like ``XMQuaternionRotationRollPitchYaw`` and ``XMQuaternionRotationAxis ``. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415597.aspx)

Comment: You may also want to take a look at the [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) wrapper for DirectXMath in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK).